# possible to get the calling stack of a specific thread of a java app?

Tags: java, jstack

My java app has over 100 threads, each thread is doing similar thing. using jstack could print the stack for all threads, but there are too many information, is it possible to print the stack of a specific thread of a java? e.g only print the thread  whose id is 100 of a java app.

Comment: Take a look at [`Throwable#getStackTrace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace()) - be warned though, this is an expensive call to make...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [getThreadInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getThreadInfo(long)) method of the [ThreadMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html) MBean. It allows you to pass a thread ID and it will return a [ThreadInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadInfo.html) datatype which contains the stack trace, thread state, etc.

EDIT: I should also add that if you are looking for something external, you can use [Threads Inspector](http://visualvm.java.net/images/threadsinsp.jpg) plugin for [jVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html). It works very nicely and allows you to choose which threads to display the stacks for in real time. Also, jVisualVM is free and comes bundled with the JDK (eg. JDK_location/bin/). The Threads inspector plugin is also free and can be installed by opening jVisualVM > Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Thread.getAllStackTraces()` to get a `Map` of all stack traces of all live threads. Search through that `Map` using `Thread.getId()` to find the thread that has the id of the one you want to print. Then `Thread.dumpStack()` to print the stack for that thread.

Sample code:

```
public void printStack(int threadId) {
  for (Thread thread : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
    if (thread.getId() == threadId) {
      thread.dumpStack();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```